# Replace multiple names in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner in python and data science. I am learning pandas. I have a dataframe and I want to replace several values inside. I've managed to find a basic code with [.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (which is very useful), but the more values I have to replace, the more lines of code I have. look at that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'sport': ['tennis', 'football', 'basketball']})
```

So :

```
df
[Out] : 
    name    sport
0   Bob     tennis
1   Jane    football
2   Alice   basketball
```

And so here is my very basic code :

```
df.loc[df['sport'].str.contains('nis'), 'sport'] = 'T'
df.loc[df['sport'].str.contains('foo'), 'sport'] = 'F'

[Out] :
    name    sport
0   Bob     T
1   Jane    F
2   Alice   basketball
```

You can easily imagine that if I have 100 rows and I whant to change many terms, I need many lines of code. 
How can I optimize my program with a clearer code please ? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's helpful that you posted an example, but kind of hard to see the bigger picture of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You could do something like: `mapper = {'nis': 'T', 'foo': 'T'}`  --> `for k, v in mapper.items():` `df.loc[df['sport'].str.contains(k), 'sport'] = v`

Answer (score 0):

As Brad Solomon commented you can create a dictionary of replacement items that you need. Then, use the for loop in python to do the replacements; for example:

```
mapper = {'nis':'T', 'foo': 'F'}
k, v in mapper.items():
     df.loc[df['sport'].str.contains(k), 'sport'] = v
```

Please note that Pandas' methods exclude missing/NA values automatically. Refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html for more information.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to modify in-place within a list comprehension

Comment: Dear Brad & Massoud, thank you very much for your help. I can confirm that Massoud's code output shows a syntax error at "=" location of the code. But Brad's code works well, so I am happy ! Thank you both of you again.